# html textbox required and the same textbox should be disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating user form where Home visit done `textbox` prevent from user directly entering the data(Textbox input comes from another form automatically),

```
<input type="text" name="hvstatus" value="<?= isset($_POST['enqnumbr']) ? htmlspecialchars($hvdone) : '' ?>">
```

When user click the submit button home visit done `textbox` should be required if textbox has empty value.

Please help

Comment: Please post your code for trying to do this.

Comment: what have you tried so far? I'm sure you can google this

Comment: You could add the `readonly`/`disabled` and `required` attributes to the `textbox`, for further validation I could recommend you do this server-side but keep in mind this doesn't stop the client from opening the browser console to remove attributes or use other methods to make changes to the `textbox`.

Comment: Add it to the question, with proper formatting, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the spec, a required field can't be disabled or readonly. That just leaves a combination of marking the field required and using JavaScript to prevent the user typing/pasting anything to the field:

HTML:

```
<form action="index.php" method=post>
  <input required type="text" name="hvstatus" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function makeReadOnly(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
var input = document.querySelectorAll('[name=hvstatus]')[0];
input.addEventListener('paste', makeReadOnly);
input.addEventListener("keypress", makeReadOnly);
```

[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/6pLwgtu6/1/)

Comment: If i use Required, user can enter the data directly to the textbox, but i want my user to enter the data in another form so i wants to disable the textbox and it will automatically fetch from the server side.. overall html textbox required and the same textbox should be disabled

Comment: I see, then you need to mark the field as disabled to prevent direct user input. I've updated the answer.

Comment: i used your code, textbox disabled but Required attribute not functioning

Comment: You're right, apparently this is the specified behaviour, which seems a little short-sighted not to anticipate this use case. I've updated my answer to use JavaScript to render the field readonly and included a working fiddle. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much...!! i found answer by disabling the button, but your code was i wanted ill user your code only.. Thank you once again...!!

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,

To prevent my user saving the readonly textbox empty value, I created my submit button disabled if the readonly textbox has empty value..using jQuery.

```
<p>Home Visit Done: 
<input type="text" id="message" name="hvstatus" value="<?= isset($_POST['enqnumbr']) ? htmlspecialchars($hvdone) : '' ?>" id="message" readonly>

<input type="submit" id="sendButton" value="save" style="width: 182px; height: 35px; font-size: 20px; background-color: green; color: white;">
```

jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){  

      var checkField;

      //checking the length of the value of message and assigning to a variable(checkField) on load
      checkField = $("input#message").val().length;  

      var enableDisableButton = function(){         
        if(checkField > 0){
          $('#sendButton').removeAttr("disabled");
        } 
        else {
          $('#sendButton').attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
      }        

      //calling enableDisableButton() function on load
      enableDisableButton();            

      $('input#message').keyup(function(){ 
        //checking the length of the value of message and assigning to the variable(checkField) on keyup
        checkField = $("input#message").val().length;
        //calling enableDisableButton() function on keyup
        enableDisableButton();
      });
    });
    </script>
```